# Can you get request params from the Camel WebSocket component?

Tags: websocket, apache-camel

I have an endpoint defined for accepting websocket connections. When the client makes the initial request to the service, it passes some GET parameters (eg `?for=purpose`) and I need to capture those values... Is there a way to accomplish that in Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, You can't do that in the current version of Camel.

However, you can access to the HttpServletRequest (which contains the request upgraded to a websocket, with all the parameters, url etc), by implementing a custom `WebSocketFactory`. This request is the first parameter of `WebSocketFactory.newInstance`. You can access the parameters in the url query by calling `request.getParameter(...)`.

Overriding the default WebSocketFactory is not a "one line configuration", but as you have already asked for this in another question, I suppose you have already done this ;-)

Comment: I have done this already, but I do not see how to put that data into the headers for the Exchange from inside either the factory or the WebSocket implementation which I wrote.

Comment: update the `connectionKey` of your `WebSocket` implementation to contains the parameters you want. This is a string, so you will have to do some parsing/extracting of this data. This connection key is sent with each message to the route, in the header `WebsocketConstants.CONNECTION_KEY`. Honestly, you should maybe write a request on the camel list/jira, because you are accessing some internal object of this component, and this code can break in a future version of camel!